# Having issues linking my domain on Namecheap with Heroku django (python) app

Tags: python, heroku, dns, namecheap

I have followed through a lot of articles on how to do this and believe I have followed it through well enough.

I bought a domain name `example.com` from Namecheap and added to my heroku app, copied the custom DNS from Heroku and added to my namecheap domain settings like so:
[image: screenshot of Namecheap dashboard]

But whenever I visit my custom domain, I get a Bad Request (400) on my screen and my heroku logs shows:

```
2019-06-25T16:36:51.564888+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.11.247.75 - - [25/Jun/2019:16:36:51 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400 26 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Infinix HOT 4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.75 Mobile Safari/537.36"
2019-06-25T16:36:51.568697+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=www.coleruche.com request_id=459dbc14-b837-404a-893e-0e80d1d763cb fwd="105.112.50.227,66.249.93.222" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=20ms status=400 bytes=199 protocol=http
2019-06-25T16:36:52.191660+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=www.coleruche.com request_id=d2df8bb7-c41a-43dd-9c5f-3f964ea14c9f fwd="105.112.50.227,66.249.93.208" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=16ms status=400 bytes=199 protocol=http
2019-06-25T16:36:52.193341+00:00 app[web.1]: 10.93.215.14 - - [25/Jun/2019:16:36:52 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 400 26 "http://www.coleruche.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 6.0; Infinix HOT 4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.75 Mobile Safari/537.36"
```

But then when I go to the heroku domain for my app, eg example.herokuapp.com, everything works well.

I believe this means I linked it well enough and my heroku app gets the request, but I can't say much from the error logged out. Why the 400 error?
The app is a django (Python) app and I have installed WhiteNoise and those other packages needed, it runs on heroku/python buildpack.

Comment: What's your `ALLOWED_HOSTS` set to in your settings file?

Comment: "Bad Request (404)" doesn't make any sense. [HTTP 404 is "not found"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/404). ["Bad request" should be HTTP 400](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400).

Comment: "I have installed Whitehouse"—I guess you mean [WhiteNoise](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html)? Please be as precise as possible when asking questions. The clearer you are the more likely you are to get a helpful answer. See [ask].

Comment: Thanks @Chris, I had to update my ALLOWED_HOSTS in settings.py to include the new domain I got. Add this as an answer let me upvote and mark it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect you need to add you domain to Django's [`ALLOWED_HOSTS`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/settings/#allowed-hosts), e.g.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['.example.com']
```